# Why my new partition disappears?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning, disk-management

I use windows 7 Pro. I shrink from Drive C for creating a new partition using Disk Management. After entering the amount of space and pressing Shrink button, the amount decreases from Partition C but I cant see new partition even in Disk Management, Why?

I used MiniTool Partition Wizard and found it, create the partition from there,assigned a letter, I saw it in My computer then. But as soon as I restart my com, it disappeared again, and at this time, I can see the volume in Windows Disk Management without an assignment or letter! Why? When I open up MiniTool, the status of this partition is hidden, why?

Is there any thing wrong with my computer/Disk? I don't know if my disk has been encrypted or not as I just started using it!

Answer (score 3):

Nothing wrong with your disk, what you describe makes sense. If you shrink or delete existing partitions you increase the unallocated space on the disk. That space is not part of a partition, but it's what's used to make new partitions.

To create a new partition in disk manager, right click on the "unallocated" section, then chose "New simple Volume". When creating a volume that way, you can decide to assign it a drive letter, mount it into an NTFS folder, or not assign a drive letter or path. It seems you didn't assign a drive letter when you created a partition with MiniTool Partition Wizard.

Unless you have already something stored in the new partition, I recommend you go to Disk Management, delete the partition, and recreate it from Disk Management. And assign it a drive letter.